# Plotting a 3D parametric curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot the 3D curve $x=e^(t)*cos(t),y=e^(t)*sin(t),z=e^(t)$, $t\in[0,1]$, by using the code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{amsbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.4}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [view={60}{30},axis lines=center,axis on top,
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$, xtick={2},ytick={2},ztick={2},no marks,axis equal,xmin=-1,xmax=4,ymin=-1,ymax=4,zmin=-1,zmax=4,enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
             \addplot3+[no markers,samples=200, domain=0:1,variable=t]({exp(t)*cos(t)},{exp(t)*sin(t)},{exp(t)});
        \end{axis}

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and nothing is plotted. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Why didn't you accept the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I think you meant to use `standalone` as a class. And then the variable name should be a macro. Also the trig functions accept argument in degrees. So you need to mention that they are in radians with an additional `r`. To remove the final connection to the inital point you can add `samples y=0`, For example for the domain `-pi:pi` you get

```
\addplot3+[no markers,samples=51, samples y=0,domain=-pi:pi,variable=\t]
                                      ({exp(\t)*cos(\t r)},{exp(\t)*sin(\t r)},{exp(\t)});
```

Full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[view={60}{30},
                axis lines=center,axis on top,
                xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,
                xtick={2},ytick={2},ztick={2},
                no marks,axis equal,
                xmin=-1,xmax=4,ymin=-1,ymax=4,zmin=-1,zmax=4,
                enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
     \addplot3+[no markers,samples=51, samples y=0,domain=-pi:pi,variable=\t]
                                      ({exp(\t)*cos(\t r)},{exp(\t)*sin(\t r)},{exp(\t)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much @percusse !